# Photon RPC or OnPhotonSerializeView is not calling

Tags: rpc, photon

I'm making a multi-player game.
my game allow player to get into same lobby and same room.
also it does instantiate playerObj.
but the problem is RPC or OnPhotonSerializeView is not calling

I putted 'Debug.Log()' function to check if it does calling these two functions by any chance... and it turn out to be it is not calling at all.
I don't know what i did wrong, or what is wrong with photon.
because my code is working fine with other simpler proj.
so it is not spelling error or something.

any help will be helpful thank you

Comment: unity does not print any error message it just didnt call those function

Comment: You are lucky that have working project which you can compare against your current one and realize what the difference is. It's hard to say more on report which simply states that something does not work.